# can i add more than 1 pages in a module in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, routing, page

I already have a module and i want to create new page which redirected from 1st of my module. 
I want to know how to create more than 1 page in a module and also how to link pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect directly from one action method to another you can use `$this->_redirect('*/*/anothermethod')` where the function is `anothermethodAction()` and is located within the same controller.

The first star indicates using the same frontname which is usually the same as the module name. The second star indicates using the same action controller which is the controller class that you are working with. So if you do `$this->_redirect('sales/order/view')` you are calling the action method `viewAction()` located in the order controller located in the sales module(this is a core module).